# How to get logs data from the Log table using log4net library?

Tags: express, iis, log4net

I implemented Log4Net with SQL Server Connection.

My issue is I can't see the logs data in the Log table until I stop IIS Express from running.

It seems weird for me, because I don't see the data right away  when I click on my link. Basically I should see the log data in the Log table when I click on the link without stopping IIS from running.

(The database is hosted remotely an I am using C#)

Any Suggestions?
Thanks!!

Comment: Are you using AdoNetAppender?

Comment: Pls post sample code as well as config section.

Comment: Yes, I am using AdoNetAppender

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AdoNetAppender uses buffering model to deliver the messages to underlying sources. Main reason why they did that way is to improve performance by not creating and commiting multiple sql transaction as opposed to one.

As per doc,

*This appender uses a buffer to store logging events before delivering them. A triggering event causes the whole buffer to be send to the remote sink. If the buffer overruns before a triggering event then logging events could be lost. Set Lossy to false to prevent logging events from being lost.*

**UPDATE:**

You can set the buffer size to something >= 1

```
<appender name="AdoNetAppender_SqlServer" type="log4net.Appender.AdoNetAppender">
      <connectionStringName value="DefaultConnection" />
      <connectionType value="System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection, System.Data, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
      <commandText value="INSERT INTO Log ([Date],[Thread],[Level],[Logger],[Message]) VALUES (@log_date, @thread, @log_level, @logger, @message)" />
      <useTransactions value="false" />
      <bufferSize value="1" />
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: _"You can set the buffer size to something > 1 as below"_ - I think you meant _"You can set the buffer size **to** 1 as below"_

Comment: .. but the config is setting it to 1, which causes the logs to be flushed immediately - which is what OP wants - and _not_ a value greater than one. Sorry to be picky.

Comment: Understood, but it is up to him to set appropriate value. Just gave the pointer where to make such changes.